# 0 devices supported on Google Play - App Update

Tags: java, android, gradle

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lighton" >

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

```
Module App build gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "lighton"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 13
    versionName "1.6"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
}

Project's build.gradle:

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
   jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I compile and generate my apk.  When I go to upload in Google Play Store I check the release and I  see 0 supported devices.

Other APK details
API levels
21+
Target SDK
26
Screen layouts
small, normal, large, xlarge
Native platforms
none
OpenGL ES versions
2.0+
OpenGL textures
none
Localizations
116 total (116 differentiating + 0 common)
Devices
Supported Android devices  0 devices

Any help would be greatly appreciated would love to re-publish my application.

Comment: is that a flashlight app with ads ? it does not support a single screen size.

Comment: Yes it's a flashlight app with ads.  It works when I build it on my phone.  Should I add support for different screen sizes, do you think it would show more devices then?  It's only one screen.

Comment: Should I add support for different screen sizes, do you think it would show more devices then?  It's only one xml Just add <spports-screens android:normalScreens="true" etc.  I will also check to make sure I have all the layout sizes with xml to support them.  I'll update it tonight and let you know my findings thanks.  It's an old flashlight app which I've updated to work on 5.0 and above.